# Why does Privoxy constantly listen 1087 port after updating macOS?

Tags: macos, proxy, privoxy

## Environment

macOS - 10.15.4 (19E266)

V2rayU - 2.1.0

## Description

After updating macOS to 10.15.4, when I try to turn V2ray on, it says

> http error - listen tcp 127.0.0.1:1087: bind: address already in use

With `lsof -i :1087`, I find that it is privoxy listening 1087 port. However, even I try privoxy kill it or restart, it will still appear soon and continue using 1087.

There is no similar circumstance before system update, I used to use 1087 for V2ray.

## Expectation

V2ray run successfully on 1087.

---

(Although change the port to another is a possible solution, it is still a strange thing for privoxy itself running in the system)

Comment: It may be hard wired to default to that port even after you kill it.

Answer (score 1):

The kernel_task thread will use port 1087.
`lsof -i:1087` and use `kill PID`, and this process cannot be terminated.

I was troubled by this problem for a long time, and finally I found out that I was using ITunes to backup my IPhone data Will occupy port 1087, and finally wait for the backup to end, successfully solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

1087 is a system and network alarm logging service.  It is an IANA registered port.

```
Well Known Ports: 0 through 1023. 
Registered Ports: 1024 through 49151. 
Dynamic/Private : 49152 through 65535
```